# What is wrong with validation loss?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

While training an CNN model (in keras), I am seeing an unusual behavior of validation loss. Though the validation accuracy seems logged correctly, the validation losses is very high (epoch 9/250 in the attached image) ? what could be the problem ?
[image]

Comment: Can past your code? It is hard to guess only by seeing the logs

Comment: Please share enough of your code to help you in solving the issue.Thanks!